# Question about increasing event.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading Geoffrey Grimmett's **Probability on Graphs**, in exercise 2.3, it says:

Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}^F$, where $F$ is finite, and let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$, and $A\subseteq\Omega$. Show that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ may be expressed as a linear combination of certain $\mathbb{P}(A_i)$, where the $A_i$ are increasing events.

The definition of increasing event:

Recall that the sample space for $G$ is $\{0,1\}^{E(G)}$. There is a natural partial order on elements of this space: $\omega \leq \eta$ if $\omega(e) \leq \eta(e)$ for all $e \in E(G)$. In other words, a configuration $\eta$ is larger than $\omega$ if any edge open in $\omega$ is also open in $\eta$.

Definition 2.4. Let $A$ be an event in percolation on $G$. We say that $A$ is increasing if $\omega \leq \eta$ and $\omega \in A$ imply that $\eta \in A$; that is, opening more edges for configurations in $A$ remains in $A$.

We say that $A$ is decreasing if $\omega \leq \eta$ and $\eta \in A$ implies that $\omega \in A$; that is closing edges remains in $A$.

I don't know where to start, is it possible to directly construct these increasing events?

Answer (score 3):

First observe that it suffices to show this for singleton events, since $P(A) = \sum_{\omega \in A} P(\omega)$. So, we only need to argue that for any $\omega,$ there exists some set of increasing events $A_i$, and reals $a_i$ such that $P(\omega) = \sum a_i P(A_i)$. For succinctness, let's say that $\omega$ is nice if $P(\omega)$ can be written in this form.

Now, the ordering $\le$ induces the finite Boolean lattice on $\{0,1\}^F$, which is ranked (one can, e.g., take the ranking function $\rho(\omega) = \sum_{i \in F} \omega_i$). Clearly the top ranked $\omega$ is nice, because $\{\omega\}$ is an increasing event. Further observe that for any $\omega,$ $$P(\omega) = P(\{\eta : \eta \ge \omega\} - \sum_{\eta > \omega} P(\eta), \tag{1}$$ and of course $\{\eta \ge \omega\}$ is an increasing event. This naturally yields an inductive argument.

Being formal about it, fix the ranking $\rho$. We will argue that $r \in [0:|F|],$ every rank $r$ element is nice, which is sufficient since every element has a rank.

As a base case, the top rank element is nice. Suppose that every element of rank at least $r$ is nice. Then for any $\omega$ of rank $r-1,$ observe that in $(1),$ every $\eta$ in the sum has rank $\ge r,$ and so is nice by the induction hypothesis, meaning that $\sum_{ \eta > \omega} P(\eta)$ can be written as a linear combination of probabilities of increasing events. But since $\{\eta \ge \omega\}$ is also increasing, this means that $P(\omega)$ can also be written in this form, i.e., that $\omega$ is nice, and we're done. It is in fact possible to write the resulting representation explicitly, you should have a go (drawing a picture of the lattice will help).